# Is ok to use String data type for timestamp in java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having trouble deciding what data type to use to store dates. I think using the Date type will make it easier for the code to be processed by the backend because there are many functions that can be used. But I'm having trouble when it's used for the response API. Each property of data type Date will return a value in the form of a timestamp. Of course this will require effort for the frontend developer to convert it to the actual date.

[image]

I've tried several Rest APIs from well-known vendors out there and then I found they use the String data type to process their Rest API requests/responses. Is using the String data type proper to use on date and time?

Comment: Assuming the entrance and exit to/from your Spring Boot application be JSON, then it is appropriate to pass the timestamps as strings, as JSON does not have a formal date time type.  However, once the string timestamp is inside your Boot application, you should convert to something like `LocalDateTime` for using it, and then also store it in your database as a proper timestamp column.

Comment: For interchange, if you don't expect the receiver to understand the exact meaning of an arbitrary number (most importantly, he can't guess the timezone, which is not necessarily fixed), use strings and [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: It very much depends on your usage. Do your "dates" really only mean dates without a time (like a birthday, implying a 24-hours timespan that depends on the timezone, as celebrating in Japan will begin some 12 hours earlier than in the USA), or is it an instant of time (timestamp, denoting some exact point in time, no matter how you call it in whatever time zone and calendar system)? You'll want to use very different representations for e.g. those two types.

Answer (score 6):

REST doesn't have a recommended date format, you should select what works best for your end-user and your system.

Generally, people prefer to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for the date-time values in text. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

RFC 3339 Date and Time on the Internet is the document to look at that says:

> date and time format for use in Internet protocols that is a profile
> of the ISO 8601 standard for representation of dates and times using
> the Gregorian calendar.

In your case, you are using epoch for a date which is totally fine and easy to convert to an actual human-readable date using java libraries.

A simple solution would be:

```
LocalDate ld = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epoch)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to arbitrary personal preference. I would personally use string since it is easier to read before sending, in transit, and upon receipt.